# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_k$ is nonnegative for a convergent sequence of nonnegative terms $a_k.$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a convergent sequence $(a_k)$ such that $a_k\ge 0 $     for all   $k\ge 1.$

Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_k\ge 0$.

I have to prove by contradiction. This is the first time I've dealt with a question like this. Can someone give me help?

Comment: By induction? I think it is not possible. And for the other side, the sequence not necessarly converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Take $x<0$ and put $\epsilon=-x=|x|>0.$ What can you say about $|a_k-x|$ for all $k$, given your hypotheses?

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, we know a sequence converges if it gets "arbitrarily close" to a number n. Let $(a_k)$ converge to some $n < 0$. At some point it will be "arbitrarily closer" to n than, say, $n/2$. How does this contradict the premise? How can you formalize this?